# Laravel send email using gmail

Tags: php, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers do not work for me. I'm trying to send email using Laravel 5 through gmail SMTP.
This is my configuration in mail.php

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'myusername@gmail.com',
'password' => 'mypassword', // uses specific-application password
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

That configuration works fine in my local machine but when I upload this to real server, it gives me

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

I've tried using the IPv4 of smtp.gmail.com which is 74.125.200.108 but it gives me the same error.
I've tried changing the port to `587` and encryption to `tls` but then it gives me

```
Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myusername@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators
```

I also tried using a new gmail account which has no 2-step verification and I enable access for less secure apps. Still does not work.

I almost giving up on this. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.